# Cocoa Touch UIWebView - Interacting with a webpage programatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to create an iPhone interface for a webpage (no, I don't want a mobile site). The website has fairly complicated Javascript, and scraping the HTML may not be worth it. Is there any way for me to "simulate" touches (or some other form of interaction i.e. selecting a checkbox)?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to interact with the content of  UIWebView is via javascript (stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)